# Draw CGContext twice within the same UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

I have a `UIView` subclass with a custom `drawRect:` method which does some expensive calculations to build a path and draws it using `CGContextStrokePath()` on the current context.

If my view has a size `(x, y)`, I want to do my custom drawing on `(0, 0), (x/2, y)` and then fill the `(x/2, 0), (x, y)` area with a mirrored image of the first half.

What is the simplest/fastest way of doing this, other than manually duplicating the points to be drawn? Maybe rendering the half view to a bitmap image context and using that one to render on both halves of the current image context? The content is animated, so `drawRect:` is roughly executed 60 times per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One efficient way of doing this is to do the draw operations on the context of a `CGLayer`, and then use the layer to draw on the current `UIView`'s context.

See [Core Graphics Layer Drawing on the Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_layers/dq_layers.html) for more details.

Basically you would do this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    const CGFloat viewWidth = view.bounds.size.width;
    const CGFloat viewHeight = view.bounds.size.height;
    CGContextRef viewContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGLayerRef layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(viewContext, CGSizeMake(viewWidth/2, viewHeight), 0);
    CGContextRef layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(layer);
    // Draw to the layerContext
    // using CGContextStrokePath() or whatever
    CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(viewContext, CGPointZero, layer);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(viewContext, viewWidth, 0);
    CGContextScaleCTM(viewContext, -1, 1);
    CGContextDrawLayerAtPoint(viewContext, CGPointZero, layer);
    CGLayerRelease(layer);
}
```

Additionally, you can store the `CGLayerRef` as an *ivar* of `UIView` so you don't recreate it every frame.

---

This solution works great in my case, but two caveats:

- It seems Apple no longer recommends using `CGLayers`, as stated [here](http://iosptl.com/posts/cglayer-no-longer-recommended/).
- In order to properly render to retina screens using `CGLayers` you have to follow the [steps detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8742178/269753)

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the `CGPath` once, you can either do this by building the whole Path as a `CGPath` instead of building it as part of the `CGContext`, or you could use the `CGContextCopyPath` to get the `CGPath` after creating it in the context. Then you could stroke the path once. Then put the `CGPath` back into the `CGContext` using `CGContextAddPath` and change the change the transform on the `CGContext` to get your mirror with a transform something like this `(-1, 0, 0, 1, width, 0)`, the -1 does the reflection about the x-axis, and the `width` should move it back to the the correct position, and stroke the path again.

Comment: Sounds like a sensible solution, thanks! However, upon additional investigation, I've found a way of doing that by drawing to a `CGLayer`. See the answer I just added. I think the layer solution is neater as you flip the whole pre-rendered half-scene, instead of dealing with individual paths.